# Using arrays instead of regular loops

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code and it works fine for small amounts of data

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim myAreas     As Areas
Dim c           As Range
Dim sTemp       As String
Dim lr          As Long
Dim i           As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
    'Refers to the worksheet using ws as variable to refer to it
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'Determine the last row based on column 9 (Column I)
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine the areas separated by empty row so as to deal with each block of data
    'And this will be based on column I
    Set myAreas = ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).SpecialCells(2).Areas

    'Change the format of column I to be as Text
    ws.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
    ws.Columns("AN:AO").NumberFormat = "@"

    'Loop through the areas (blocks of data)
    For i = 1 To myAreas.Count

        'Empty the variable because we will use it again
        sTemp = Empty

        'Extend the block to include 38 columns after column I
        With myAreas(i).Resize(, 38)
            'Debug.Print .Address 'Gives you the address of the range

            'Sort data by column I which is the first column in that range
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

            'loop through cells in column I
            For Each c In .Columns(1).Cells

                'Adjust the format of the cell
                c.Value = AddZeros(c.Value, 2)

                'if the cell value="01 or "11" then the inside lines will be executed
                If c.Value = "01" Or c.Value = "11" Then

                    'Put asterisk in the column AM and AP
                    c.Offset(, 30).Value = "*": c.Offset(, 33).Value = "*"

                    'Cell in AO column equals to cell in AN
                    c.Offset(, 32).Value = c.Offset(, 31).Value

                    'Foramt number to be equal to 9 length
                    c.Offset(, 31).Value = AddZeros(c.Offset(, 31).Value, 9)
                    c.Offset(, 32).Value = AddZeros(c.Offset(, 32).Value, 9)
                End If
            Next c
        End With

        'Deal with the block again
        With myAreas(i).Resize(, 38)

            'Loop through column S cells
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells

                'if cell value not empty and not equal 0 then
                If Trim(c.Value) <> Empty And Trim(c.Value) <> 0 And Trim(c.Value) <> "" Then

                    'put the cell value into the variable sTemp
                    sTemp = Trim(c.Value)
                End If
            Next c

            'Loop again through cells in column S
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells

                'if cell in column J equals 01 or 11 then the cell value will be equal to sTemp
                'else leave it empty
                If c.Offset(, -10).Value = "01" Or c.Offset(, -10).Value = "11" Then c.Value = sTemp Else c.Value = Empty
            Next c

            'Loop again through cells in column S to fill the empty names
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells
                If c.Value = "" Or c.Value = Empty Then c.Value = c.Offset(-1).Value
            Next c

            'Loop through column AE
            For Each c In .Columns(23).Cells

                'If cell value is a number the convert it to positive
                If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then c.Value = Abs(c.Value)

                'trim the value in cell in column AL
                c.Offset(, 7).Value = Trim(c.Offset(, 7).Value)

                'Column J equals to 1208643 then
                If c.Offset(, -21).Value = "1208643" Then
                    'Column J next row cell
                    c.Offset(1, -21).Value = "800107"

                    'Column P next row cell
                    c.Offset(1, -15).Value = "1050-101"
                End If

                'if the value in cell in column AE is number and the value in column J equals 1208643 then
                If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Offset(, -21).Value = "1208643" Then
                    c.Offset(, -1).Value = "A0"
                ElseIf IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                    c.Offset(, -1).Value = "A1"
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Next i
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub

Function AddZeros(makeLonger As String, numberDigits As Integer) As String
Dim x           As Long
For x = 1 To (numberDigits - Len(makeLonger))
    makeLonger = "0" & makeLonger
Next x
AddZeros = makeLonger
End Function
```

However when trying it with large amounts of data about 60,000 rows it took so much time .. so is it possible to optimize it to make it faster?

Comment: Improving functional code is more the domain of [CodeReview.se]. You'll want to read their [expectations of a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow their rules and suggestions. You'll get a lot of good help over there to improve your code in many ways.

Comment: I have posted a thread there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227396/using-arrays-instead-of-regular-loops